# Remove element from the array by the index with Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

i have a array with integers numbers filled out by users dinamically as he uses the app, i got the operation add element to arrays (Fieldvalue.arrayUnion), but, i need delete the some elements periodically, the function *arrayRemove* needs a value of the index but as this value is filled in by the user, then I won't know exactly who he is, so it would be more useful to delete the elements by their indexes? (the indexes in the image):

[image: firebase]

My ask is: IS possible natively remove the elements of array by the index and not for its value?

Comment: Firestore doesn't provide operations to work with list elements by index.  You can only remove by item value.  Otherwise, you have to read the document, make changes to the list in memory, then write the list back to the document.

Comment: This is a big disadvantage regarding the SQL Databases...

Comment: Please feel free to file a feature request with Firebase support: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support